# postmessage to browser's opener window from callback in Internet Explorer 11.0.x

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, popup, payment-gateway, razorpay

I am trying to write a callback in my app that opens a popup, does some stuff and responds to the popup opener window to mark the action as complete.

The popup uses `window.opener.postmessage()` method to communicate with the opener window in browser.

Its working in most browsers.
However, Internet Explorer 11.0.x is not able to postmessage, whereas 11.192.x is able to. I have not checked with IE,9/10.

The error is `Permission Denied` and `window.opener` is `undefined`
Is there any way to resolve this and make my popup send message to opener window in Internet Explorer 11.0.x?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I haven't tried this on Internet Explorer, but let me know if it works for you.

Create an empty object to hold your data on the window object.

eg.

`window._myData = {};`

Create a function on the window object. The function is what does the stuff you want to do, sets the data and gets called when the new window closes.

eg.

`window._popupClosing = function(data){ 
    this._myData = data;
    console.log('done....', this._myData); 
};`

Open your popup window.

eg.

`var w = window.open('https://google.com','_blank');`

Set a timer to check if the window has been closed. Then run your function.

eg.

`var timer = setInterval(function(){
    if(w.closed){
        clearInterval(timer);
        window.parent._popupClosing(window.location.href);
    }
}, 1000);`

Remember to close the new popup from a script within the popup using

`window.close();`

## Combining these

`window._myData = {};
window._popupClosing = function(data){
    this._myData = data;
    console.log('done....', this._myData);
};
var w = window.open('https://google.com','_blank');
var timer = setInterval(function(){
    if(w.closed){
      clearInterval(timer);
      window.parent._popupClosing(window.location.href);
    }
  }, 1000);`

Remember to close the new popup when you are done. `window.close();`

> If you can post your data to an endpoint then retrieve the data from the endpoint in your popup close function, that will be better than sending data between windows. I think.